# Find link element closest to click

Tags: javascript, oop, nearest-neighbor

I'm working on a little js puzzle I found online which states to write some js to find the closest link to a mouse click event. I have a good start at it, but I was wondering if the community could help me find ways to improve it.

My basic approach is to basically loop through all links, figure out their distance from the mouseclick event, and then store it until the next iteration or all elems have been exhausted, in which case I would return the closest element.

I'd like feedback on the following:

- Is my algorithm accurate? What are the pitfalls?
- Is there a faster, better approach to determining the closest link?

One issue I can think of is that I'm basically using the top left point of a link element to determine distance, but what if the click was actually on the link itself or on the lower right of the element? The link should be the closest element, but with my implementation, the next link could be closer and trigger an incorrect result.

```
<body>

<p><a href="" id="1">link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="" id="2">link 2</a></p>

<script>
  window.FindNearestElementToBodyClick = {
    init: function() {
      document.addEventListener("click", this.findElementClosestToClick, true);
    },

    findElementClosestToClick: function(e) {
      var x = e.x;
          y = e.y;

      var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("a"),
          closestElem = {};

      for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        var eX = elems[i].offsetLeft,
            eY = elems[i].offsetTop;

        var diff = Math.sqrt((Math.abs(eX - x)*2) + (Math.abs(eY-y)*2));

        if(closestElem.e == undefined) {
          closestElem.e = {e: elems[i], diff: diff};
        }

        if( diff < closestElem.diff ) 
          closestElem.e = {e: elems[i], diff: diff};
      }

      console.log(closestElem);
    }
  }

  FindNearestElementToBodyClick.init();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint` first, to determine if it occurred inside of a link (of course, I think you'd have to traverse up through its parents to make sure you're not clicking on a nested element inside an `<a>`)

Comment: It depends on what you want to define as "closest":  the nearest corner?  the nearest center?  the nearest top-left (as in your code)?  Otherwise it looks like you already have a good solution.

Comment: In addition, I'd suggest using a center (`offsetTop + offsetHeight / 2`, similar for x-coord) rather than a corner, the corner behaviour would go against my expectations as a user.

Comment: Note that you don't need to run `document.body.getElementsByTagName("a")` on every function call; it's a live node list, so at any point in time that new `<a>`s are added or removed, the node list will be accurate. Just a tiny improvement

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to decide where you want the performance to be best - onload or onclick. Unless the anchors are going to move around* you could probably do some work up-front, even if it was just to set up a collection of all the anchors in the page and their locations. Then the dom wont have to go off and figure that out every time the user clicks somewhere.

Theoretically each anchor has a zone in the page in which any click is nearest to it (if that makes sense) and those zones are static (assuming the anchors dont move*). You could figure those zones out onload and then each click could be mapped straight to the correct anchor.

But thats probably not worth the extra effort. What you have seems pretty sensible to me - unless there are a gazillion anchors and/or the hardware is terrible (mobile perhaps but you did say click).

*fluid layouts/dynamic content etc would invalidate that assumption. You could look into resize events and update the zones/collection when things are moved around.